# Getting a static external IP

Tags: static-ip, external-ip

I'm not even sure if this is possible.  My external Ip changes about once every 3 days.  How would I prevent it from doing so?  I have to connect a domain to my IP and I can't give it a domain to connect to (in the case of "no-ip.com").  Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the DHCP configuration at your ISP, you could keep the same address for a very long time if you never shut down your internet connection. If you have an always-on connection then your IP address *should* not change unless your modem turns off or otherwise is disconnected.

Other than that, @Jason is correct. A good ISP will only charge a modest fee for a static address but some force you to subscribe to "business" internet in order to get a static address.

Answer (score 9):

Call your ISP. Request a static IP address from them. Pay the additional costs to your ISP for the static IP address.

Comment: How much are these static Ips normally?

Comment: I pay 1 galactic credit per month.  But in all seriousness, the pricing is all over the map.  It could be very cheap, or very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic DNS?  I use that for a server I run out of my home.  Check out dyndns.com. It's free.

Comment: I go with a static IP even for a fee before using dyndns.com.

Comment: The problem with this is, I have to provide my domain with an Ip, for whatever reason, it won't accept other domains.